# In hyperledgerfabric 's transaction flow ,will the orderer send blocks to peers in network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In hyperledgerfabric 's transaction  flow ,will the orderer send blocks to the peers in network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes , orderer recieves the endorsed transaction from the client , make it as a ordered block and sends that block to the peers (committing peers) in the organisation

Answer (score 2):

The picture below shows ordering service sending endorsed transactions to the committing peers.
[image: Transaction Step 4]

Comment: can u tell me who approves the joining request of peer adding to channel?

Comment: Adding a new peer into the existing network can be done by a peer who is already part of the network, so hope no approval needs.But adding a new Org into network will have the approval process @SahithiDyavarasahetti